# Google Checkout using HTML Code Similar to PayPal

Tags: google-checkout

I am trying to integrate a Google Checkout "Buy Now" button, and am hoping that there is some HTML code available similar to adding a Buy Now button in PayPal. I have not had much luck as yet, and was wondering if someone would be able to point me in the correct direction?

I also need to be able to add a callback address into the script (not set through the google checkout admin panel).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I've found checkout to be largely obscure. You'd think the google interface would be very clear but often it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all documented in the [Google Checkout API](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/).  Additionally, there is [a guide](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Comparison_Part_I) that shows the different ways you can implement Google Checkout depending on your available resources.